# Getting No Output in HTML5

Tags: html, css

Why this code not giving any output ?
i am not understand what's the problem.

```css
.a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your div has no content, and even though you gave it a height it has none since its parent has no height. Try adding a height to the parent like:

```css
.a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
</div>
```

As the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) on height state:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
 
}
body {
height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
</div>
```

Comment: Divs are block level by default. And did you even run your own example? It's blank!

Comment: Yes I know the div isnt block level it is inline-block

Comment: Um, what are you talking about? Divs are block level by default, and yet you set the display to block anyway.

Comment: OK, now you've just copied my answer, plus with no explanation.

Comment: Uh excuse me I confusing bitwin a & .a